# 67k Stories Published with 0 Story Impressions

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-insights, insight

My Facebook Insights is showing I have 67k stories published within the last month but ZERO Story Impressions [screenshot](http://o7.no/RIqphI). Have I set something up incorrectly? How can this be possible?

Comment: Did you actually publish 67k stories?

Comment: @MikeRobinson To me knowledge--how can I check?

Comment: Well what site is it? I'm guessing they probably thought it was a spam attempt.

Comment: @MikeRobinson it's a legitimate media property that received 33,893,210 visitors during the same time period (1 month)... Negative feedback in Insights is low but maybe they're flagging it as spam?

Comment: Stories flagged as spam should also show up under Insights->negative feedback. If there aren’t any spam reports listed there, then I’d say that’s most likely not the problem.

Comment: @CBroe Yeah there are only 0.1069 Story Spam Reports / 10K Impressions. So if that isn't the problem then what is?